# How do I stop the CORS error on Cpanel with a form submission?

Tags: cors, cpanel

I have an Ajax contact submission form from an HTML page that keeps getting this error

```
Access to fetch at 'https://api.web3forms.com/submit' from origin 'https://<domain>' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I've added this to the .htaccess file, which is in the root directory.

```
<IfModule mod_headers>  
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin '<domain>'
</IfModule>
```

But it's not working. Am quite familiar with how CORS works and this usually does the trick. Anyone have any tips? Thanks

Comment: you added that to api.web3forms.com's root directory?

Comment: It's just calling that page to do a POST. I've added it to the directory with the page that I've created via CPanel